# What's wrong with the following public directory setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just built a Webpack project:

```
static/ // where I have the js and css file
index.html // the main file
```

And placed it inside the `public/` folder in an Express setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('public/index.html')
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

But I get these errors:

```
http://localhost:3000/static/app.79c874fce37c5d0a32117271eb04a7f8.css 
http://localhost:3000/static/app.57fd4b2335b940c7b8d1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the content of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>istaging-viewer</title>
  <link href=/static/app.79c874fce37c5d0a32117271eb04a7f8.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=app>
    <script src=/static/app.57fd4b2335b940c7b8d1.js></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(Those files exist in the `/static/` directory).

How should I change the Express code so Express can find those files?

**EDIT:** I tried this ...

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('static/index.html')
});
```

[image]

... but I'm still getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/static/app.79c874fce37c5d0a32117271eb04a7f8.css 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/static/app.57fd4b2335b940c7b8d1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried this to serve the static files:

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

I still get the same errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/static/app.79c874fce37c5d0a32117271eb04a7f8.css 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/static/app.57fd4b2335b940c7b8d1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You are handling the index.html file via express, but not the static assets, which express needs to be aware of. See this page please: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. The first line of code is a straight copy and paste for your project directory structure.

Comment: @martinczerwi I tried your suggestion. Please see my **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Please try this `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Comment: @martinczerwi That didn't work ... because I'm now using the structure of **EDIT** I don't have a public folder anymore.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Then you need to change the index file, because the static folder is the root of your requests. You need to reference files like `localhost:3000/app.87d...123.css` (just edited, I forgot the port number ;)

Comment: @martinczerwi Is there another way of doing this? Because if I do it like this I have to modify each URL in the built files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as your app/main js file is in the same folder as your index.html, then change

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('public/index.html')
});
```

to

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html')
});
```

Ideally, however, your file structure should look something like:

```
app.js
static/
    index.html
    js/
    css/
    img/
```

that way, you'd reference it this way

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('static/index.html')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get this: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\alex\express-test\static\index.html'
   at Error (native)`

Comment: I have to remove the the `public` folder maybe?

Comment: I get the same error with the new code: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\alex\express-test\index.html'

    at Error (native)`

Comment: I did what you suggested please see my **EDIT**.